# Javascript / JQuery - Hide 5 Divs, then Show 3 Random Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I have 5 divs with the class 'testimonialBox'. Each div has different content. I want all 5 to start out hidden.

Then, I want to have 3 of those divs with that class randomly chosen and shown. They must be 3 non-repeating, unique divs (that is, the page may show the first, third, and fourth divs, but not the first, first, and fourth divs).

Here is the code I am currently trying to use:

```
var testimonials = $("div.testimonialBox");
  $(testimonials).hide();

var divs = $("div.testimonialBox").get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,3);
  $(divs).show();
```

How do I do this?

Comment: That code runs fine for me, make sure you included jquery and have the class name present on all of your divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is weird, but its working fine for me without repeating divs
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ETkPlK9C1U